# log a report from memory_profiler

Tags: python, profiler, memory-profiling

I am profiling my code using memory_profiler

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def whatever():
    ....
    ....
```

So, as many of you may know I am getting an output on the screen similar like this:

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
==============================================
     3                           @profile
     4      5.97 MB    0.00 MB   def my_func():
     5     13.61 MB    7.64 MB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     6    166.20 MB  152.59 MB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     7     13.61 MB -152.59 MB       del b
     8     13.61 MB    0.00 MB       return a
```

My question is:

Since the @profile process takes a lot of time, I was wondering if I could somehow log/store this output, and leave the script running, maybe during the night.

My idea is to use the decorator @profile in many def functions, and store all the results somehow in one single TXT or in many different TXT files, this is not importatnt, the important is if that would be possible.

Comment: You can use [Python logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Comment: Can't you just pipe the result? That's the quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: @Veedrac, sorry I do not follow you, I am not very into `memory_profiler`, I just know how to make it work, but I do not even know yet where the output comes from. That would help I think.

Comment: Just `run_my_thing > output.txt` in the shell. Circumvent `memory_profiler` altogether. Obviously it's not ideal.

Comment: Thanks Veedrac, I actually don't care about how ideal it might be, if it works then it would be enough for me, so thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub><sup>As from the comments:</sup></sub>

If you just run

```
run_my_thing > output.txt
```

in the shell you can store `stdout` in a file.

This will circumvent memory_profiler altogether. Obviously it's not ideal to just redirect `stdout`, but if it's for human analysis it shouldn't be a massive problem.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it, but seems pretty simple - From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler):

> REPORTING
>
> The output can be redirected to a log file by passing IO stream as
>   parameter to the decorator like @profile(stream=fp)
>   .

```
>>> fp=open('memory_profiler.log','w+')
>>> @profile(stream=fp)
>>> def my_func():
    ...     a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    ...     b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    ...     del b
    ...     return a
```

---

For many txt/log files i.e. keeping result for various functions/code blocks separately - pass a different file object while decorating a function:

```
fp=open('memory_profiler.log','w+')
@profile(stream=fp)
def func1():
    # statements

fp2=open('memory_profiler2.log', 'w+')
@profile(stream=fp2)
def func2():
    # statements
.....
```

Downside: Lot of open connections.

---

Elegant way to log to multiple files is to make use of `RotatingFileHandler`:

> Sometime it would be very convenient to use logger module specially
>   when we need to use RotatingFileHandler.
>   The output can be redirected to logger module by simply making use of
>   LogFile of memory profiler module

.

```
from memory_profiler import LogFile
import sys

sys.stdout = LogFile('memory_profile_log')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best example to follow, to send [memory_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) output to a log file can be found in its repo:

https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/blob/master/examples/reporting_logger.py